# Difference between 貝 and 貝殻

Tags: words

I would like to know if there's any difference between 貝 and 貝殻, and if these words are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

貝 has several meanings but usually it refers to the shellfish as an animal.
貝殻 means only  the shell.

かい【貝】貝殻をもつ軟体動物。ハマグリなどの二枚貝、サザエなどの巻き貝、ツノガイなどの掘足類を主にいう。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/35183/meaning/m1u/貝/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/35183/meaning/m1u/%E8%B2%9D/)

かいがら【貝殻】貝の軟体を外側から包む石灰質などからなる硬い物質。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/35485/meaning/m1u/貝殻/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/35485/meaning/m1u/%E8%B2%9D%E6%AE%BB/)

Comment: So, for example, "picking up shells on the beach" would be 貝殻を拾う, and 貝  means "mollusk  (with shell)" rather than "shell" (海松貝という貝 = a mollusk called mirugai), doesn't it?